# Jquery datepicker icon not working

Tags: php, jquery

I implemented a jquery datepicker to selec check in and check out date.
In my design I have glyphicon-calendar,When I click the text box calendar appears but when I click the icon itz not working.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <label for="email">
    <?php echo TransText::gettrans($lang_trans_id,8)?></label>
    <div class='input-group date'>       
        <input type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" name="chenin" class="form-control" id="check_in">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
    <label for="email">
    <?php echo TransText::gettrans($lang_trans_id,9)?></label>
    <div class='input-group date' >
        <input type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" name="checin" class="form-control" id="check_out">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My Jquery function**

```
$(function () {
    $("#check_in").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: today_date,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',


        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
            $("#check_out").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
        }
    });
    $("#check_out").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate: today_date,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

        onSelect: function (selected) {
            var dt = new Date(selected);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
            $("#check_in").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what's error you are getting in web console or firebug console ?

Comment: You could add it to your binding - `$("#check_in, .glyphicon-calendar:first").datepicker({` & `$("#check_out, .glyphicon-calendar:second").datepicker({`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not write any code to show datepicker on glyphicon-calendar click.Please use `show` function to open the datepicker.Give id to respective spans like `checkinspan` and `checkoutspan`. then use the below code

```
$("#checkinspan").click(function() {
  $("#check_in").datepicker("show");
});
$("#checkoutspan").click(function() {
  $("#check_out").datepicker("show");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in order to trigger calendar on image click.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#check_in").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
      $("#check_out").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $("#check_out").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      var dt = new Date(selected);
      dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
      $("#check_in").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
    }
  });
  $('.input-group-addon').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-group.date').find('input[type="text"]').first().focus();
  })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="email">
    <?php echo TransText::gettrans($lang_trans_id,8)?>
  </label>
  <div class='input-group date'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" name="chenin" class="form-control" id="check_in">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="email">
    <?php echo TransText::gettrans($lang_trans_id,9)?>
  </label>
  <div class='input-group date'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" name="checin" class="form-control" id="check_out">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I removed the `today_date` variable to make the demo. You can use it.